# Bigcartel mobile only

Tags: html, css, bigcartel

I'm trying to get my bigcartel page to show

```
<div style="margin-top: 0px; img align: middle">
      <a href="/products"><img width="420" height="42" style="vertical-align:middle;" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/52c5068376.png" alt="PAF ENTRY"></a>
</div>
```

on mobile devices only while trying to show an exact copy of the code for browsers only
here is the page
http://pafclub.bigcartel.com/entry

And this is what I have so far:

```
<div class="mobileHide">
<div style="margin-top: 0px; img align: middle">
<a href="/products"><img width="420" height="42" style="vertical-        align:middle;" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/52c5068376.png" alt="PAF ENTRY"></a>      </div>
<style type="text/css">
.mobileHide { display: inline;}
/* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px){  .mobileHide { display: none;}}
</style>

<div class="mobileShow">
<div style="margin-top: 120px; margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;">
<a href="/products"><img width="420" height="42" style="vertical-align:middle;" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/52c5068376.png" alt="PAF ENTRY"></a>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.mobileShow { display: none;}
/* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px){ .mobileShow { display: inline;}}
</style>
```

it shows one version of the image but when I check on a mobile device there is no image at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme has code that adds a margin to custom page bodies that you'll need to override. Add this to the bottom of Customize Design > Advanced > CSS to remove it:

```
#entry .page {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then for your entry page, all you'll need is the following code to have the image display centered properly (on desktop and mobile)

```
<a href="/products">
  <img style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;max-width: 427px;display:block" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/7da3920e19.png" alt="ENTRY">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have worked on your problem, and got solution for this. Please check the code.

```css
.mobileHide { display:table; height:100%; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; width:100%;}
.middle{ display:table-cell; height:100%; vertical-align:middle; width:100%;}
.middle a{ max-width:80%; display:inline-block;}
.middle a img{ max-width:100%;}

html, body {
     height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="mobileHide">
<div class="middle">
    <a href="/products">
    <img width="420" height="" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/52c5068376.png" alt="PAF ENTRY">
    </a>  
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where do i put the top half of the code, CSS? Also this worked in making my image right in the middle which i really wanted so thanks for that.